# Writing HTML to XML file

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing

I'm in the middle of a project that has me grabbing HTML from a page, store the data in XML, and then from there grab the data in between specific tags and export it to an email file.

I'm been doing research through the internet and on stackexchange to understand the basics of trying to accomplish this task. However, I'm guessing this may not be as simple as just a few lines of code to write the HTML to XML. I'm not looking for the direct codes, but more for a general right direction to head in.

Comment: I have a few comments. 1. You should be able to parse HTML with most XML parsers. 2. I think what you need is to control the storage format so that what reads the data is compatible with the stored data, but if the HTML data changes you only have to change the code that stores it. 3. If you are going to parse the data from HTML to XML and then read the data out of XML it would be cheaper to store the data in a lighter format, like JSON. Not sure if that helps, but just some thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

They are a bit different. HTML is a markup language used to display websites, traditionally a combination of xml and a style sheet. If you want to convert to xml you should lookup extracting the relevant data from the html page using a scraper then exporting your structured data to xml. There are many scraping tools in a variety of languages including some gui tools.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is not always valid XML.  XHTML is supposed to be valid XML, but in the wild you'll see many websites that do not follow the standard correctly (but still render properly in a browser), for example using unclosed `<br>` tags.  You'll also still see a fair number of HTML 4.x and lower websites out there, which will almost certainly be invalid as XML.

What you probably want is an HTML parsing library.  There are several depending on the platform you're using.  Many of these will support DOM parsing and manipulation of HTML documents, and will allow you to extract the data you want.  You could then write that data to a valid XML file, or to whatever other destination you want.

I've used [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for .NET and [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for Python in the past; both work well.  If you're using some other platform, there's probably a library out there to do similar things, but we'd need to know what platform you want.

Since you're doing this in JavaScript, you'll probably want to use jQuery or Angular.JS for your DOM manipulation and parsing, both of which are widely supported and documented options for DOM access and manipulation.

If you're doing it in Node.JS, there are other libraries as well such as jsdom and cheerio

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. This going to be done through JavaScript.

Comment: In that case you probably want to use something like jQuery or Angular.js to do your DOM manipulation and parsing.  Updating answer.